# JDBC Query Clarification

Tags: java, jdbc, sybase

I have an insert query for Sybase Db which inserts one varchar value and 2 integer values into a table which is returning a error.

```
The table column datatypes are Varchar,Int,Int
```

The query is as shown below

```
sql_str = "INSERT INTO TempTable VALUES(" +
                      "'"+ 'Y' +"',"+ "DateDiff(ss,'12/31/1969 19:00:00','"+ secBegin +"')" +","+ "DateDiff(ss,'12/31/1969 19:00:00','"+ secEnd +"')" +")";
```

and its uses 2 String values i.e. secBegin and secEnd

```
String secBegin = "04/03/2012 10:08:24";
String secEnd = "04/03/2012 10:09:07";
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Insert error: column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.
```

and its pointing to the insert query shown above as the erreneous line.

Is there any error in the jdbc query shown above.

Comment: I'd strongly suggest to use a `PreparedStatement` with parameters instead of concatenating values into a query. Also Be explicit with the columns in the `INSERT` statement.

Comment: @all : Thanks for all the replies, it seems that the Table had some issues, which is resolved now.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try this should it work :

```
sql_str = "INSERT INTO TempTable VALUES("Y",DateDiff(ss,'12/31/1969 19:00:00','"+ secBegin +"'),DateDiff(ss,'12/31/1969 19:00:00','"+ secEnd +"'))";
```